# LIBCMTD.lib(crt0.lib) LNK 2019 error in project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've created an OpenGL (**GLEW**) project in **VS2012** and it is working perfectly. Now I've moved the project to **VS2013.** I've created a new project and set the project's environment the same as I did in VS2012:

- Character Set:--------------**Use Multi-Byte Character Set**
- Include Directories:--------**C:\Foo\glew-1.9.0\include**
- Library Directories:--------**C:\Foo\glew-1.9.0\lib**
- Additional Dependences:-**opengl32.lib; glu32.lib; glew32.lib**
- Runtime Libary:-------------**Multi-Threaded Debug (/MTd)**

All code is exactly the same as before, but when I run the program, I get this error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in
function ___tmainCRTStartup c:\FooBar\...\Projects\OpenGL\OpenGL\LIBCMTD.lib(crt0.obj) 
OpenGL
```

I can't see why this same project with the same settings and code doesn't work when it is an exact duplicate.

Comment: Don't ever copy the CRT files, like libcmtd.lib.  You must always use the ones in VS's vc\lib directory.  And an /MTd program will link msvcrtd.lib, never libcmtd.lib.  Delete the copy you have in that OpenGL directory.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @SpicyWeenie LIBCMTD is the debug version of the static multi-threaded C runtime library, and according to Microsofts licensing you cannot use than in the release version of code, I would check you are compiling in debug mode:

- in debug mode use /MTd as the runtime library
- in release mode use /MT as the runtime library

This will hopefully help, if not, then clean your project before building, and if that does not help either, apply liberally with swearing before creating a new project and ensuring it is a `Windows Console Application` and not a `Windows Application`  (the last one has been the most common cause of the exact error you are describing for me, and happens mostly to me when moving between versions of Visual Studio (2008 to 2010 or 2010 to 2012)

Sincerely hope this helps, but if it doesnt let me know and maybe I can figure out whats wrong:)

Comment: I found the problem. For some reason, the Entry Point (Linker->Advanced->Entry Point) was empty. I just had to add "WinMain" into the field and it solved the issue.

Comment: excellent, and thanks for sharing that, I will add it to my checklist of reasons for that error as it is the bane of my existance when moving code from version to version.  Cheers.

Comment: ahh just realised the entry point issue is what I was talking about before with the windows console and windows app. Your issue was the other way round from mine by the sounds of it: set as a console app when it is actually a windows app.